# objectHTMLDivElement error in html . Appending a child into another element . But shwoing the error

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to insert a child in another dom element. But when i added to the element it shows `objectHTMLDivElement` . No element there.

```js
let modal = document.getElementsByClassName("my-modal");

let bl_span = document.createElement("span");
bl_span.className = "bl-close-button";
bl_span.textContent = "&times;";
modal.appendChild(bl_span);
```

What is the problem ?

This is the actual function:

```js
function add_A_PopUp_Modal(parent_node , added_html , neighbour_node , modal_id , span_id){
  let modal = document.createElement("div"); //create a modal div
  modal.className = "bl-modal"; //Add generic classname for all modal
  modal.id = modal_id; //Modal id for specific modal
  
  //Adding HTML for every modal
  let bl_modal_content = document.createElement("div");
  bl_modal_content.className = "bl-modal-content";
  let bl_modal_content_id = "bl-modal-content-"+modal_id;
  bl_modal_content.id = bl_modal_content_id;
 // bl_modal_content.innerHTML(`<span class="bl-close-button" id=${span_id}>&times;</span>`);
  let bl_span = document.createElement("span");
  bl_span.className = "bl-close-button";
  bl_span.id = span_id;
  bl_span.textContent = "&times;";
  let  parser = new DOMParser();
  let doc = parser.parseFromString(bl_span, 'text/html');
  bl_modal_content.appendChild(doc.body);
  parser = new DOMParser();
  doc = parser.parseFromString(added_html, 'text/html');
  bl_modal_content.appendChild(doc.body);
  // let modal_inner = `
  //       <div class="bl-modal-content" id=${bl_modal_content_id}>
  //       <span class="bl-close-button" id=${span_id}>&times;</span>
  //       <div>
  // `
  modal.innerHTML = bl_modal_content;

  //Added the modal in a div before the neighbour node
  parent_node.insertBefore(modal, neighbour_node);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try changing the class to id

Comment: @AadityasivaSabarinathan This is not a problem. Because in the main content I have an id. I think it's another problem

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), not a single DOM object.

Either use id and use function `getElementById` to get the `modal` DOM object.

Or in the existing code try accessing the first element in array.

```
modal[0].appendChild(bl_span);
```

Comment: Every time i am creating a new node . So here id doesnt matter

Comment: @AkrabulIslamImran In that case access element with the array index `modal[0]`